# The difference between a presheaf and a set

Tags: intuition, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory

I just started studying complex geometry and in all the literature sheaf theory shows up. For me this is still a rather abstract object and I have a hard time understanding the difference between a (pre)Sheaf and a set.

As an example, in an article to explain Hodge Decomposition, we have $X$, a $m$-dimensional Riemannian manifold. Now the sheaf of smooth $n$-forms on $X$ is denoted by $\mathcal{A}_X^n$.

I don't understand why we cannot simply work with the set of $n$-forms. What is in this case the key difference between taking the sheaf of $n$-forms and just taking the set of all $n$-forms on X.

Comment: In general, we also care about n-forms on open sets of X. We have a set of n-forms for each open set of X, not just for X. The sheaf can be viewed as a collection of these sets together with some data (restriction maps) telling you how to compare n-forms on different open sets.

Comment: So it is okay to see a sheaf as giving a set of (in this case) n-forms on every open set, with some additional restrictions on the glueing? And thus "the sheaf of smooth n-forms on X" just means that for every open subset U of X we have the set of smooth n-forms on U?